# How to properly list items from array after splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have some example code:

```
var array = [];
array[0] = {id:0};
array[1] = {id:1};
array[2] = {id:2};
```

Now array looks like

```
[Object{id=0}, Object{id=1}, Object{id=2}]
```

I use splice:

```
array.splice(0,1);
```

And we have:

```
[Object{id=1}, Object{id=2}]
```

When I try `for` or `for ... in` length will be only 2 and I can't iterate it in normal way. Result of loop is:

```
undefined
Object{id:1}
```

In first case (when we use `for`) I understand why it didn't work, but `for ... in` should return indexes 1 and 2 not 0 and 1...

Anybody can explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sure you can. Just iterate from 0 to array.length (which is 1)... `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { ...`

Comment: The code you have posted is fine (see my working example of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/PNeRk/). Can you post your looping code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What did you try? If I issue

```
var array = [];
array[0] = {id:0};
array[1] = {id:1};
array[2] = {id:2};
array.splice(0,1);
for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++)
    console.log(i + ":", array[i]);
```

the engine correctly outputs

```
0: Object { id=1 }
1: Object { id=2 }
```

(but the array indices change to `0` and `1`, perhaps that is what confuses you; remember that [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) by default removes from element `0` onwards and shifts all remaining elements downwards).

**Update:** apart from the fact that you can always get the `id` property of the individual objects using `array[i].id`, you can delete array elements without shifting the other elements using the `delete` operator. After I replace `array.splice(0,1)` with

```
delete array[0];
```

the output shows

```
0: undefined
1: Object { id=1 }
2: Object { id=2 }
```

Comment: Exactly! But problem is that i dont want decrement indexes because in some cases i must refer to it. I should use delete or what?